# Webpack scan html templates for assets and process them

Tags: html, webpack, assets

In my project I use Webpack mainly for bundling `.js` and `.css` files.
Main question is about images. When images are used in `.css` files Webpack process them and exports to `/dist` folder. Which is fine, and works like a charm.

What I want to accomplish is pretty same story but with `.html` files. But! Html files are in different location then my wepack-app.

```
-/root
--/design
-----/src
--------/js
--------/css
--------/images
--------/...
-----/dist
--/templates
--/...
```

Is it possible to e.g pass additional path to scan for assets?
I don't want to produce new `html`. Just check which assets are used in html files from `root/design/src/images` then process them (same as from css files) and copy to `/dist`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new entry point (a js file) that will require all the html files that you want to be processed.

You will need to install [`html-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader) in order to allow webpack to "understand" html files.

Comment: Ok, but how tell to html-loader that something like `{% static 'path/to/image.png' %}` is kinda path to static file?

Comment: Is that kind of template engine? If so you will need a specific loader...